# loop index twig with condition

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, twig

I want to make looping from array multidimention like database. that's example array that my made:

```
array[0]['name_product'] = 'big cola';
array[0]['size'] = '4';
array[1]['name_product'] = 'cfc';
array[1]['size'] = '1';
array[2]['name_product'] = 'hot dog';
array[2]['size'] = '1';
array[3]['name_product'] = 'pizza';
array[3]['size'] = '6';
```

I want to make looping with 2 condition, this is size == '1' and size > '1'. after it I want create loop from every condition, example:

size == '1', so:

```
no     name_product      size
1      big cola           4
2      pizza              6
```

size > '1':

```
no     name_product      size
1      cfc                1
2      hot dog            1
```

how about to make "no" is increment it with array and condition in twig ?
I hope you can help me. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, I'm assuming you're looking for conditional loops. Twig has built-in support for that, [here's the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition). It was added in twig 1.2.

In your case you would make two loops (for the two tables) like this:

```
{% for product in products if product.size == 1 %}
    {# your first table #}
{% endfor %}

{% for product in products if product.size > 1 %}
    {# your second table #}
{% endfor %}
```